# Extreme points of the intesection of a convex set and a half space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following claim as part of my research on finance, but my attempt has been unsuccessful. I would appreciate if anyone could provide a proof or any related results, books, or papers.

Definition: An extreme point of a convex set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a point in $S$ that cannot be expressed as a convex combination of two distinct points that belong to $S$.

Claim 1: Take any bounded convex set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^N$. Pick any $a \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and define a half space as $H= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^N: a \cdot x \ge c \}$. Any extreme point of $S \cap H$ can be expressed as a convex combination of at most two extreme points of $S$.

This claim seems true when I picture a convex set and a half space in $N=2$ and $N=3$, and I suspect this is true for any $N$.

Ultimately, I would like to show the "infinite dimensional version" of the claim: Take any bounded convex set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ of functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Pick any $a \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, and define a half space as $H= \{g\in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}: \int^1_0 g(x) a(x) dx \ge c \}$. Any extreme point of $S \cap H$ can be expressed as a convex combination of at most two extreme points of $S$.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing that there are hidden depths to this question buried in your research, but I feel compelled to point out that your half-space definition feels incomplete. What restrictions are there to ensure that $\int_0^1 g(x)a(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is a sensible integral? It certainly doesn't work with just any functions in $\Bbb{R}^{[0, 1]}$.

Comment: You need more conditions, take $S = \{0\} \times (-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which has no extreme points. Now intersect with half space $x_1 \ge 0$ and we see that the result has an extreme point at the origin.

Comment: Perhaps assume $S$ is compact?

Comment: @RobertIsrael That'd be natural in the $\Bbb{R}^N$ case. In the "ultimate" goal, no topology is specified. I'd like to hear more from the asker on this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out the issue. Yes,  for the finite version, let us assume that $S$ is compact. For the infinite version, given the purpose of my research we can focus on the space $\mathcal{S}^*$ of non-decreasing functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, and assume that $a(\cdot)$ is continuous. We can then take any topology on $\mathcal{S}^*$ that makes $\int^1_0 g(x) a(x) dx$ continuous in $g$, and then consider a compact, convex set $S\subset \mathcal{S}^*$ with respect to this topology. I hope that my explanation makes sense, and even a proof for the finite version greatly helps :)